# Rails Bundler.require taking too long .As a result Phusion Passenger throws error on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, bundler, passenger

I am trying to start my phusion passenger server. And the error i get is

`An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.`

I followed this wiki from phusion passenger
https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems

I have found out that my rails app gets stuck in config/application.rb in Bundler.require line. Looks like I have a lot of gems and Bundler.require takes a lot of time, and the phusion passenger server exits by then.

How can i overcome this issue.

Here is the server link http://zenkars.com/

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to defer requiring your gems until they're actually needed. You can do this by using `Bundler.setup` instead of `Bundler.require` in your `application.rb` file. See Myron Marston's article, [5 Reasons to Avoid Bundler.require](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/12/5-reasons-to-avoid-bundler-require) and [A Simple Rails Boot Time Improvement](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/12/a-simple-rails-boot-time-improvement/) by Pan Thomakos for details.

That might just delay the problem, however, leading to slow requests instead of slow startup. It would be a good idea to track down which gems are the slowest to require and see if there are newer versions or other alternatives to speed them up.

You might also try a newer version of Ruby, as some older versions have known performance issues with lots of requires. See [Profiling Ruby, or, How I Made Rails Start Up Faster](http://blog.tddium.com/2012/11/20/profiling-ruby/) by Greg Price for details on that.